# Show that system is orthonormal and complete orthonormal

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, hilbert-spaces, orthogonality

Let $\{\psi_n(x)\}$ - orthonormal system in $ L_2[a,b]$ and $\{\chi_n(x)\}$ also orthonormal system in $ L_2[b,c]$.

Where $ L_2[a,b]$ - space of equivalence classes of set $ \mathcal{L}_2[a,b]$.

Let system of linear independent vectors $ E = \{e_\alpha\} $ complete if $ E^\perp = \{0\}$

Let $ \mu,\lambda \in \mathbb{R}^+ : \mu^2 + \lambda^2 = 1 $

Consider:

$ \varphi_n(x) = \lambda\psi_n(x), x \in [a,b] \\ \varphi_n(x) = \mu\chi_n(x), x \in (b,c] $

$ \phi_n(x) = \lambda\psi_n(x), x \in [a,b] \\ \phi_n(x) = -\mu\chi_n(x), x \in (b,c] $

1. How to show that $ \{ \phi_n(x) \}$ and $ \{ \varphi_n(x) \} $ - non orthonormal systems in $ L_2[a,c] $ ?
2. How to show that, if $ \{ \psi_n(x) \}$ - complete in $L_2[a,b]$ and $\{\chi_n(x)\}$ - complete in $L_2[b,c]$, then $\{ \phi_n(x), \varphi_n(x) \}$ - complete orthonormal systems in $ L_2[a,c] $?

I think there is may be important these facts:

1. $ E^\perp = \{0\} $ if and only if  $ cllin E  = L_2[a,b] $. E in some Hilbert space.
2. If $ E = \{e_\alpha \} $ - orthonormal in $ L_2[a,b] $  then next statements are equivalent: 1) E - Hilber basis 2) E - closed system 3) E - complete system

Comment: I don't think that $\lambda$ and $\mu$ are really that important here. Try to solve this with $\lambda=\mu=1/\sqrt{2}$. Have you got any idea of where to start?

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro I think there is may be important these facts:

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro  I think there is may be important these facts: 1) $ E^\perp = \{0\} $ if and only if  $ cl lin E  = L_2[a,b] $. 2)E in some Hilbert space 2) If $ E = \{e_\alpha \} $ - orthonormal in $ L_2[a,b] $  then next statements are equivalent: 1) E - Hilber basis 2) E - closed system 3) E - complete system

Comment: OK. So start showing something, and add it to the body of your question using the EDIT button. People will be much more willing to contribute once you have shown some effort.